# How can I increase the loglevel in duckdb-wasm?

Tags: webassembly, duckdb

It seems like duckdb's default loglevel is set to INFO. How can I increase this to WARNING?

[image: browser console output of duckdb wasm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide more details in how you have deployed duckdb-wasm?

If you have control over the JS embedding, you should be able to change the logging level by changing the call to the constructor of ConsoleLogger, it can take an (optional) parameter that will set the logging level.

If you are using https://shell.duckdb.org, I don't think that option is exposed to users, but it's doable and might make sense to add an option like https://shell.duckdb.org/?logLevel=X (this is not currently implemented).

Carlo, maintainer of [duckdb-wasm](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb-wasm)

Comment: I'm using "@duckdb/duckdb-wasm": "^1.28.0"
If I call the constructor with I higher log level it does not change. I believe this will create an additional logger and not change the level of the already existing one

Comment: Turns out the ConsoleLogger was created elsewhere in the code, but I overlooked this